# Manual Calculation of Jaro Distance

Tags: r, jaro-winkler

I am attempting to validate the R function `stringdist` from library `stringdist`.

Using example

`1 - stringdist('John J Smith', 'John Smith', method = 'jw', p = 0)` it returns `0.9444444`

Where `p = 0` implies that the Winkler component of Jaro-Winkler is not used.

I am attempting to reproduce this result using the formula shown in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) and this [documentation](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/docs/api/com/aliasi/spell/JaroWinklerDistance.html) however just can't seem to get my manual calculation to align.

In my example below, there are 5 half transpositions and so `floor(5/2)` results in `t = 2`.

There are 10 matching characters, ensuring that the distance between the matching characters is not greater than 5.

[image]

The resulting calculation is:

[image]

Comment: `library(stringdist); stringdist('John J Smith', 'John Smith', method = 'jw', p = 0)` returns `[1] 0.05555556` for me. Can you double-check?

Comment: Apologies, please subtract the result from 1.0 (updated)